# Only inserts in to database once then fails

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small section of code. When the table is empty this code works fine and enters in to the table fine. But then if i try again then this fails with the error?

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

```
// On my Function page

    function admin(){
                    connect();

                    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO results 
                    (t_id, pos1, pos2, pos3)
                    VALUES  ('$_POST[t_id]','$_POST[pos1]','$_POST[pos2]','$_POST[pos3]')")
                    or die ("Error.");

                    $b = "Updated fine</b></a>.";

                    return $b;
                        exit();
            }

    // Then on my main page

<?php
    include ('functions.php');
    if (isset($_POST['admin'])){
    $admin = admin();
    }
?>

            <div id="content">
                    <div id="admin">
                        <form action="" method="post">
                            <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%"><?php echo "$admin"; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%"><label>Track <input type="text" name="track" size="25" value="<? echo $_POST[t_id]; ?>"></label></td>
                 </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%"><label>Position 1<input type="text" name="pos1" size="25" value="<? echo $_POST[pos1]; ?>"></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%"><label>Position 2 <input type="text" name="pos2" size="25" value="<? echo $_POST[pos2]; ?>"></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%"><label>Position 3 <input type="text" name="pos3" size="25" value="<? echo $_POST[pos3]; ?>"></label></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%"><input class="save" type="submit" value="" name="admin"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Welcome MysqlInjection, come and feel like at home :)!

Comment: Use `mysql_error()` to see errors. Output queries to see problems in them. (And what @genesis said: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: i get the "or die" error

Comment: yes i know i need to try and secure my code and been told i need to escape the strings but still in the learning process so thought i should try and get this working first before looking at securing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your table schema, I can only think you have UNIQUE t_id and you want to insert the same ID into it.

Several way to debug:

- Use `or die ("Error: " . mysql_error());` instead of just `or die ("Error.");`
- Check your table schema: `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and write it down on your question, so we can see if it's causing error.

Comment: perfect thanks that worked perfectly. not sure why it failed because the UNIQUE t_id i was using was different every time.

Comment: vote up and pick as right answer. Also, can you tell us what caused problem and how you fixed it? write it in your answer, so that future user coming to this question can also fix their code.

Comment: i had the t_id as a unique id which caused an error when there was already more than one row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess. Maybe you are entering the same values twice, and they happen to violate some unique constraint?

But you make another mistake: you forget to call `mysql_real_escape()`. That is [bad](http://xkcd.org/327/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us of the error?  It sounds like you're hitting a primary key violation, perhaps by trying to insert the same id more than once.

That aside, your code is riddled with security holes.

You should not be inserting variables straight from the POST into your query.  All I have to do is submit `'; DROP DATABASE` and I can completely wreck your system.

Additionally, you're injecting values directly from POST into input fields, meaning I can set up a button on my site that submits `" <script type='text/javascript'>window.location='http://mysite.com'</script>` or something along those lines and take over your page.

This may sound terse, but you should do some googling or pick up a book regarding textbook security issues with websites.

EDIT: Just saw your comment about learning security.  My advice is to be proactive about this sort of thing, because being reactive is often too late to fix problems.